# approximation for the value of $\#\{ n \leq x \leq q: \gcd(x,q)=1\}$.

Tags: number-theory

is there a way to find an approximation in terms of $n$ for the value of $\#\{ n \leq x \leq q: \gcd(x,q)=1\}$.

Here we suppose $q$ is a fixed number.

It is clear that it has to be $\leq \phi(q)$, since

$\#\{ n \leq x \leq q: \gcd(x,q)=1\}= \phi(q)-\# \{1 \leq x \leq n: \gcd(x,q)=1\}$.

Comment: What is $(\cdot, \cdot)$? Is it the greatest common factor?

Comment: yes. thanks. Edited my question

Comment: As a rough heuristic: As the multiples of any factor of $q$ are roughly evenly distributed in the interval $[1, q]$, it would stand to reason that the union of all such multiples of any factor (and therefore its complement, the set of integers relatively prime to $q$) would also be evenly distributed. This would give you $\phi(q) (q-n)/q$ as a first-pass approximation.

Comment: @ConnorHarris suppose I have $b \leq q$. Does that mean $\# \{n \leq q \leq b : (x,q)=1 \}$ would be $\phi(q) (b-n)/q $ ?